# How can I calculate arcore image score in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

I am setting up a android app by Kotlin, and I want to get image score for arcore.

On [this page](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/c/augmented-images/arcoreimg) they say:

> Run `arcoreimg eval-img` to get a quality score between 0 and 100 for each image.

And I just found a program for Linux, macOS, Windows to unzip the `arcore-android-sdk-1.11.0`.

I want to calculate arcore image score via my Android app.

How can I calculate the image score if the arcore team doesn't support it?

I found some posts that run the Windows program on Android, but It is *'How To Run Windows App(EXE) on Android Mobile'* by use emulator. However, I want to write code that the app can calculate on its own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be to host arcoreimg tool in a docker and query this service instead. I know it is not ideal, but might be an option

Comment: I was just thinking about taking a picture on Android and scoring it
That might be one way.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you take a picture on Android and use API to your "arcoreimg tool" to score it

Comment: hi @nimuni , after taking the picture, how can i calculate the score using android app?? Please help to tell me.

Comment: @Akhilmittal
I made a server which calculate score of image. And I call API in android app. That's it